# iOS Deployment Target (8) Using new API from iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a simple app that I built in XCode 7 (iOS9 beta) and its a using a new property from iOS9.

```
allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates
```

I have my deployment target set to iOS8 and am just wrapping that property in code like so:

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
        instance.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    }
```

This works great and I can archive and build an adhoc IPA file via XCode. However, now I'm trying to do it via command line.

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration AdHoc archive -archivePath /Users/andrewherrick/Desktop/MyApp.xcarchive
```

It fails with the following. Is it for some reason trying to compile against iOS8 only where that property wouldn't exist? Do I need to do something special to tell it to compile against iOS9?

```
error: property
      'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' not found on object of type
      'CLLocationManager *'
```

Comment: FYI - replace `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {` with `if ([instance.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {`. Always check for the method/class, never check the iOS version.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help my compilation issue. any thoughts there? as I said i'm able to run the app on both iOS8 & iOS9 if it's been compiled via adhoc archive